# Search GAL with Viewpoint (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to figure out how to find contacts in the corporate directory with Viewpoint.  I have the 'global address list', but I can't figure out how to get all contacts or search for a specific contact, any ideas?

```
puts "gal object (#{gal.name})"
```

produces:

> gal object (GAL Contacts)

What I'm trying to get is the users telephone numbers.

The #items method produces a single OpenStruct:

> `#<OpenStruct opts={:parent_folder_ids=>[{:id=>"AAMkADFiZmUzYzJiLTFiZGEtNGExMS05Y2VjLTNlNzZhM2ZiMDIyNwAuAAAAAAAuu1wbQUm2T5mdHCmSmclSAQB6eKCzoHFYSbreAs6F5kmYAAAAAAUOAAA="}], :traversal=>"Shallow", :item_shape=>{:base_shape=>"Default"}}, restriction={}>`